# AWS Cognito User Pool - SignInSuccesses CloudWatch Alarm and Metrics in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have been unsuccessfully trying to implement in CloudFormation what is described in the AWS documentation: **Metrics for Amazon Cognito user pools** [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/metrics-for-cognito-user-pools.html] for the Metric '*SignInSuccesses*', specifically "To count the total number of failed user authentication requests, use the CloudWatch Math expression and subtract the Sum statistic from the Sample Count statistic."

I've made a bit of progress with resolving various errors with my template from the errors provided by CloudFormation; however, I seem to have hit a wall and have now been getting the generic "*Invalid metrics list*" which has been hard to diagnose how to move forward.  I've also searched around a bunch to try and find other examples of Cognito Metrics/Alarms examples, as well as, have tried to achieve this manually through the console, both with no success.

My template so far:

```
  CognitoFailedSignInAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: !Sub Cognito-${ApplicationName}-FailedSignIn-Alarm
      AlarmDescription: Cognito UserPool Failed Sign In Attempts Alarm
      AlarmActions:
        - !Ref AlarmsTopic
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      TreatMissingData: ignore
      Threshold: !Ref AlarmThreshold
      Metrics:
        - Id: m1
          MetricStat:
            Metric:
              Dimensions:
                - Name: UserPool
                  Value: !Ref UserPoolId
                - Name: UserPoolClient
                  Value: !Ref UserPoolAppClientId
              MetricName: SignInSuccesses
              Namespace: AWS/Cognito
            Period: !Ref AlarmPeriod
            Stat: SampleCount
          ReturnData: False
        - Id: m2
          MetricStat:
            Metric:
              Dimensions:
                - Name: UserPool
                  Value: !Ref UserPoolId
                - Name: UserPoolClient
                  Value: !Ref UserPoolAppClientId
              MetricName: SignInSuccesses
              Namespace: AWS/Cognito
            Period: !Ref AlarmPeriod
            Stat: Sum
          ReturnData: False
        - Id: TotalMinusFailed
          Expression: m1-m2
          Label: FailedCount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic CloudFormation error *Invalid metrics list* was masking two issues, a small formatting issue but more importantly the 'ReturnData: true' was missing on the Expression metric which is required.

The following deployed successfully and appears to work correctly.  Hope that helps someone else out there!

```
Metrics:
  - Id: totalLogins
    MetricStat:
      Metric:
        Namespace: AWS/Cognito
        MetricName: SignInSuccesses
        Dimensions:
        - Name: UserPool
          Value: !Ref UserPoolId
        - Name: UserPoolClient
          Value: !Ref UserPoolAppClientId
      Period: !Ref AlarmPeriod
      Stat: SampleCount
    ReturnData: false
  - Id: successfulLogins
    MetricStat:
      Metric:
        Namespace: AWS/Cognito
        MetricName: SignInSuccesses
        Dimensions:
        - Name: UserPool
          Value: !Ref UserPoolId
        - Name: UserPoolClient
          Value: !Ref UserPoolAppClientId
      Period: !Ref AlarmPeriod
      Stat: Sum
    ReturnData: false
  - Id: e1
    Expression: totalLogins-successfulLogins
    Label: Failed Logins
    ReturnData: true
```

Answer (score 0):

My template does enable all the metrics, i build it last year but what i can find related is this property at AWS::Cognito::UserPool

```
  UserPoolAddOns:
    AdvancedSecurityMode: ENFORCED
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-userpooladdons.html

you can try "AUDIT" too